# Magento 2: Creating configurable product using the REST API

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, api, rest-api

In order to create configurable product I need to create configurable product, virtual product and finally connect them.

Example of json request got from here: [How do I create a configurable product using the REST API v2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156374/how-do-i-create-a-configurable-product-using-the-rest-api-v2)

I am wondering why do I need this section below in configurable product?

```
        "configurable_product_options":[
         {
           "attribute__id":"193",
           "label":"Colour",
           "position":0,
           "values":[
             {
               "value_index":340
             },
             {
               "value_index":341
             }
           ],
```

I noticed that this section is required in able to connect virtual product to configurable connect later. But values has no meaning.

In virtual product I can assign any value I want. What is the purpose of this values?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code, I hope its work for you.

created a simple product with 'color' attribute  and simple product ids are 1011,1012 & 1013.

```
<?php
/********* Create Configurable Product By Rest API *********/
try {
    $url = "http://siteurl.com";
    $apiusername = 'apiusername';
    $apipassword = 'apipassword';
    $userData = array("username" => $apiusername, "password" => $apipassword);


    $ch = curl_init($url."/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    $product_data= '{
                    "product": {
                                "id": 0,
                                "sku": "config_1",
                                "name": "Config Product",
                                "attributeSetId": 4,
                                "price": 20,
                                "status": 1,
                                "visibility": 4,
                                "typeId": "configurable",
                                "createdAt": "string",
                                "updatedAt": "string",
                                "weight": 0.8,
                                "extensionAttributes": {
                                    "stockItem": {
                                        "isInStock": true
                                        },
                                    "configurableProductLinks": [1011,1012,1013],
                                    "configurableProductOptions": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 0,
                                            "attributeId": "93",
                                            "label": "Color",
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "isUseDefault": true,
                                                "values": [
                                                    {
                                                        "valueIndex": 11
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "valueIndex": 12
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "valueIndex": 13
                                                    }
                                                        ]
                                        }
                                                                ]   
                                   }
                            }
    }';

     $ch = curl_init($url."/rest/V1/products");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$product_data);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     }catch(Exception $e){

           echo $e->getMessage();

     }
      var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to create a configurable product.

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "MS-Lime",
    "name": "Lime Tee",
    "attribute_set_id": 9,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "configurable",
    "weight": "0.6",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "11"
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "category_id": "12"
            },
            {
                "position": 2,
                "category_id": "16"
            }
        ]
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "The Dime Tee is soft, comfortable and durable. You will love the way you look in this tailored tee shirt."
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "material",
            "value": "148"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "pattern",
            "value": "196"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "color",
            "value": "52"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see I am not using
`configurable_product_options` 
in my body. This is not the mandatory field. You can totally skip this.